# Is there any way to ensure type safety in java at compile time without generics

Tags: java, generics, compile-time, type-safety

I am writing a java application using older version of java SDK which doesn't support Generics. So, How can I assure type safety during compile time. I can use instanceof(). But, it does ensure run time type safety. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Safe from using `Object`s in every collection or map, I doubt you'll find a solution. Generics was introduced for this reason. By the way, `instanceof` is an operator, not a method.

Comment: You can never make the compiler behave in a certain way. Its either Generics to check at compile time or use `instanceof` at Runtime.

Comment: Thank yoy Mena and Nikhil.
@Mena - nice observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bad old days, collections and maps were typically stuffed inside a class whose methods expose the right types. So, to create a "typesafe" list of integers, you might do something like:

```
class IntegerList {
    private final List delegate = new ArrayList();

    public boolean add(Integer i) {
        return delegate.add(i);
    }

    public Integer get(int index) {
        return (Integer) delegate.get(i);
    }

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return delegate.iterator();
    }

    // etc
}
```

Of course, you're stuck with a non-typesafe `Iterator`, but you could achieve that with another similar `IntegerIterator`. Note that this is basically what generics does for you automatically.

Why are you using such an antiquated JDK?

Comment: I think that your code would not compile without adding a cast operation to the get method.  But if you really want compile time type safety without generics, I would copy/paste the ArrayList code and explicitly change the type parameter (T) to whatever you are using (Integer).

Comment: @emory you're right. The code was just an example to show the strategy.

Comment: Thank you Matt Ball. The project I am working on is pretty old project and coded using old JDK. So, I need to do some modifications in the code without disturbing the other parts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either uses abstract/interfaces (i.e. limit things by making them all implement the same interface) or you need to use generics.

There aren't many other options, this is exactly what generics was added to solve.

Comment: Can you please share a simple code snippet on how to limit things making them all implement the same interface/abstract class.

Comment: The easiest way is by doing what Matt Ball suggested, you wrap the collection in a utility class and have the utility class accept a specific Interface.

Comment: That work around looks excellent. I thought you meant some other workaround for it. If so, Please share an example. It would be helpful to others as well.